# Immutable Hash and Array implementation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, hash, immutability

Is there simple **immutable** hash and array implementation in javascript? I don't need best speed, a reasonable speed better than a clone would be good.

Also, if there are **simple** implementations in Java or some other languages that can be **easily understood and ported** to JavaScript, it would be also nice.

**UPDATE:**

The goal isn't to just froze the hash (or array), but to make an efficient implementation of update operation - update of immutable hash should return a new immutable hash. And it should be more efficient than doing it by "clone original and update it".

Native JS types have complexity of update something like O(1), with cloning the complexity will be O(n), with special immutable data structures (what I asked for) it will be 0(log(n))

**UPDATE2:** JavaScript already has Array / Hash :

Yes, but they are mutable, I need something similar but immutable, basically it can be done very simply by cloning `hash2 = hash1.clone(); hash2[key] = value` but it's very inefficient, there are algorithms that made it very efficient, without using the `clone`.

```
hash1 = {}
hash2 = hash1.set('key', 'value2')
hash3 = hash1.set('key', 'value3)

console.log(hash1) // => {}
console.log(hash2) // => {key: 'value2'}
console.log(hash3) // => {key: 'value3'}
```

**SOLUTION:**

It's not an implementation for immutable hash, but more like a hack for my current problem, maybe it also helps someone.

A little more about why I need immutable data structures - I use Node.js and sort of in-memory database. One request can read database, other update it - update can take a lot of time (calling remote services) - so I can't block all read processes and wait until update will be finished, also update may fail and database should be rolled back. So I need to somehow isolate (ACID) read and write operations to the in-memory database.

That's why I need immutable arrays and hashes - to implement sort of MVCC. But it seems there is a simpler way to do it. Instead of updating database directly - the update operation just records changes to database (but not perform it directly) - in form of "add 42 to array db.someArray".

In the end - the product of update operation will be an array of such change commands, and because it can be applied very quickly - we can block the database to apply it.

But, still it will be interesting to see if there are implementation of immutable data structures in javascript, so I'll leave this question open.

Comment: What is "hash and array". JavaScript has arrays; are you thinking of an indexed collection something like `java.util.Vector`?

Comment: Every object in javascript can be thought of as a hashtable<K,V> where you can access the value of by saying obj[key]

What exactly are you loking for?

Comment: Yes JavaScript has Arrays but they are mutable, I need something similar but immutable.

Comment: you need "an efficient implementation" but "not the best speed"..?

Comment: nope, there is nothing like that in js, and no straightforward way to implement, afaik.. all the implementations you can do will always be slower than the standard native mutable objects.

Comment: ```"efficient implementation" but "not the best speed?``` Yes, it should be two or five times slower than native mutable types, but not as terribly inefficient as by doing it with `clone` operation.

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin Do you know about `Object.preventExtensions()`, `Object.seal()`, and `Object.freeze()`?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas interesting, but not compatible with a lot of curent to slightly older browsers.. ie* for eg

Comment: `Object.freeze()` - it freezes the object, immutable data structures provide an efficient way to do slightly modified copies of object, it's a totally different thing.

Comment: I don't think you'll get exactly what you want, but you could make some clever use of the `prototype` or `__proto__` property to make something that behaves like a very efficient copy of another object. New properties, and modifications to existing props is simple. deletions require more code. native iteration...now thats getting tough.

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is old but I thought people that were searching like me should be pointed to Facebook's [Immutable.js](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) which offers many different types of immutable data structures in a very efficient way.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same requirements for persistent data structures for JS, so a while ago I made an implementation of a persistent map.. https://github.com/josef-jelinek/cofy/blob/master/lang/feat.js

It contains implementation of a balanced tree based (sorted) map, and a naive copy-on-write map (and unfinished persistent vector/array).

```
var map = FEAT.map();
var map1 = map.assoc('key', 'value');
var value = map1.get('key');
var map2 = map1.dissoc('key');
...
```

it supports other methods like `count()`, `contains(key)`, `keys(into = [])`, `values(into = [])`, `toObject(into = {})`, `toString()`

The implementation is not too complicated and it is in public domain. I accept suggestions and contributors too :).

**Update**: you can find unit tests (examples of usage) at https://github.com/josef-jelinek/cofy/blob/master/tests/test-feat.html

**Update 2**: Persistent vector implementation is now there as well with the following operations: `count()`, `get(i)`, `set(i, value)`, `push(value)`, `pop()`, `toArray(into = [])`, `toString()`

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make an object immutable is to hide it inside a function. You can then use the function to return either the default hash or an updated version, but you can't actually store an immutable hash in the global scope.

```
function my_hash(delta) {
    var default = {mykey: myvalue};
    if (delta) {
        for (var key, value in delta) {
            if (default.hasOwnProperty(key)) default[key] = value;
        }
    }
    return default;
}
```

I don't think this is a good idea though.

Comment: Let me introduce you to `Object.freeze()` `:P`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas whoa, neat! I did not know about that.

Comment: Thanks, but the goal isn't to freeze an object but an efficient way to do slightly modified copies.

Comment: let me introduce you to Object.freeze() performance http://jsperf.com/object-freeze-performance I could not believe that at first.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to clone an object in Javascript I'm aware of, is the one contained in [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#clone)

Shortly:

```
_.clone = function(obj) {
  if (!_.isObject(obj)) return obj;
  return _.isArray(obj) ? obj.slice() : _.extend({}, obj);
};

_.extend = function(obj) {
  each(slice.call(arguments, 1), function(source) {
    for (var prop in source) {
      obj[prop] = source[prop];
    }
  });
  return obj;
};
```