# Since const is not usefull to create an immutable array in JavaScript (I don't know exactly why), what is the best way to create an Immutable array?

Tags: javascript

This question has nothing to do with [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314187/immutable-hash-and-array-implementation-in-javascript) in my opinion, I'm trying to understand some behavior about the javascript core, I don't want a library or something.

I'm trying to understand why this code actually modify `const originalArray`

```
const originalArray = [0, 2, 1, 1, 1];

var newArray = originalArray;

var removed = newArray.splice(0,3);

console.log(originalArray);//return [ 1, 1 ]
```

But at the same time this is not possible:

```
const originalArray = [];
originalArray = [1];
```

So, how can I create a truly immutable Array without a library?

Comment: Did you try `Object.freeze(arr)`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe is not a duplicate, I've edited the question to avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason modifying `newArray` also modifies `originalArray` is because variables in JavaScript are just references to objects. When you say `newArray = originalArray`, you're not copying the array, you're copying the reference. So when you say `newArray.splice(0, 3)`, you're modifying the array referenced by `newArray`, which `originalArray` *also* references.

Similarly, in JavaScript, the word `const` refers to the reference being constant, not the underlying object. That is to say, you can call mutating methods like `.splice` on a `const` variable with no issues. It's when you try to reassign the variable using `=` or similar that you run into errors.

As others have noted, `Object.freeze(_)` will make it so you cannot modify the inner object, achieving "immutability" in that you will not be able to modify the underlying object.

For example, if you do the following:

```
const originalArray = Object.freeze([1, 2, 3]);
let newArray = originalArray; // you can easily use `const` here, but I don't want to confuse the two concepts
newArray.splice(0, 3); // TypeError: Cannot add/remove sealed array elements
```

If you want a copy of the array that you can modify without modifying the original array, `Object.freeze` alone will not help you. You will want to "deep copy" the array, which can be done through various methods (easily Google-able, so I will redact them as this answer is getting longer than hoped).

Comment: To clarify, if you replaced the `let` in the second statement of the example with `const`, you would achieve the same behavior. If you replaced the `let` with `const` and removed `Object.freeze`, the `.splice` would be allowed and it would have the same behavior as the code in your original question.

Comment: Thank you @River your explanation is very clear. I think the better way instead of `Object.freeze` is `var newArray = originalArray.splice();`

Comment: That's a good way of deep copying a shallow array. That is, if the elements are just numbers or immutable objects, this will work. However, if you have mutable objects inside the array and modify individual objects, they will still be modified in the original array. To be very certain you're not accidentally creating multiple references to the same object, I recommend using lodash.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) for that.

```js
const arr = Object.freeze([1, 2, 3]);
console.log(arr);
arr[1] = 7;
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I don't think this is the correct answer to the body of the question, which is asking why the original array is affected when you modify the new array.

Comment: Thank you @Tamas, but I don't understand this behavior of const.

Answer (score 2):

const isn't creating a constant variable, like you think, it creates immutable binding. If you write const arr = [] and then arr = {}, you'll get the error. Even Object.freeze freeze only the top level. For example:

```
const x = Object.freeze([1, 2, 3, [3, 4, 5]]);
x[3].push(20);
console.log(x)
```

You will get [ 1, 2, 3, [ 3, 4, 5, 20 ] ], if you want it to be completely immutable you have to freeze it recursively, but it hits the performance.
You can also create a copy of the array like that and use the new one

```
const x = [1,2,3,4,5]
const y = x.slice(0, x.length)
```

Comment: Thank you @Vlaev it's definitely a big point against `Object.freeze`